# Загрузка изображений с очисткой ненужных

Tags: php, imagesource

Не могу додумать наиболее простой способ очистки папки на сервере от ненужных изображений.

Допустим.
Юзер решил написать пост, содержащий изображения.
Пишет текст с помощью визуального редактора, а значит база не имеет отдельного поля для адресов.

Добавляет картинку. Та, в свою очередь, сохраняется на сервере и отображается в поле редактирования текста.
Добавляет какой-то текст и ещё несколько картинок.

После. Решает удалить все картинки кроме одной.
Сохраняет пост.

Как находить изображения уже загруженные, но удаленные в визуальном редакторе, соответственно не нужные?

Решение...Решение?
Вначале я решил сделать добавление изображений в формате BLOB.
То есть, картинки видны в форме, но ещё не загружены на сервер. И уже после отправки формы, запускаю событие AFTER_INSERT, разбираю текст, создаю изображения из блоб и загружаю их на сервер, затем заменяю все src.
Работает. Здорово. Привет DomDocument.

Но.
Нужен ресайз изображений.
Выполнять его средствами js, как-то уж нууу, не знаю. Плюс валидация в таком исполнении увы только с помощью js.

Значит нужно всё-таки с помощью php грузить.

И вот тут - затык.
Как создавать временную папку?
То есть.
Ну загрузили мы картинки в tmp.
Допустим в user_id/tmp/
А если юзер в итоге удалил все картинки?
Да, можно сравнить наличие img в тексте и удалить папку tmp.
Но если пишется 2 поста одновременно под учёткой одного юзера?
Наверно можно создавать разные tmp папки для каждой статьи.
Но как передавать их адрес скрипту при следующем очередном добавлении картинки?

Вобщем думаю, думаю, и не вижу решения.
Поделитесь соображениями уважаемое комьюнити.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такая мысль:

1. При написании поста создаем некий временный рандомный идентификатор поста. Для надежности можно совместить таймстамп + id автора + рандом.
2. Картинки загружаем, скажем, в `uploads/temp/{TEMP_ID}/`.
3. При отправке поста картинки анализируются (можно отдельным полем отправлять массив картинок, что используются).
4. Нужные картинки копируются в постоянную папку, скажем `uploads/post-{POST_ID}/`.
5. Оставшиеся картинки, вместе с папкой `uploads/temp/{TEMP_ID}/` удаляются.

Но, например, если не отправить пост и очистить сессию браузера. И поста как и не бывало, но картинки остались и их никто не удалит. Проэтому раз в неделю-месяц проходимся cron'ом и удаляем все старые картинки, которые могли случайно остатся. У них дата создания должна быть не меньше недели, думаю.
Как-то так.

Comment: Но если генерировать TEMP_ID на сервере, может случится проблема, когда вы открыли вкладку, потом нажали "дублировать вкладку" и у нас будут две вкладки с одинаковым TEMP_ID, в которых можно писать два разных поста. И будут баги.  Но это не точно. Как решение, могу предложить на стороне клиента добавлять еще рандома, то есть будет (таймстамп + id автора + рандом сервера) + рандом клиента. Или подгружать его по AJAX - тогда каждый раз будет отправлятся новый запрос и будет новый TEMP_ID. Вот.

Comment: Вот. И я так думаю, что временные айдишники могут дел натворить.

Comment: Может быть, если только привязаться к сессии юзера?

Comment: А если загружать все картинки во временную папку, на фронте сохранять ID всех картинок, а при отправке поста отправлять картинки которые нужно удалить и которые нужно сохранить. И картинкам нужно давать наверное рандомные имена тогда

Comment: @Rmn, `"Может быть, если только привязаться к сессии юзера"` не совсем понял вас

Comment: Имел ввиду, при загрузке первого img, создавать временную папку с названием, равным идентификатору текущей сессии юзера. Соответственно остальные картинки также будут загружены туда же. В этом что-то есть. Но эффективно ли...

Comment: Но если из-под одной сессии писать одновременно два поста - обе будут сохранятся в одну папку. И потом будут баги, картинки одного поста удалятся вместе с картинками второго. А так - у нас будет идентификатор с привязкой к id автора и таймстампу, еще и рандом - коллизий (совпадений) быть не должно